# NHibernate: Ordering results by a collection of IDs

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nhibernate, case

Ok so this is my problem with NHibernate.

I have a set of IDs which changes dynamically so there is no way I can hardcode the values. Using these IDs, I need to order a query with these IDs.

Set of IDs (type 'long') to order with (these change dynamically):

```
{8, 6, 23, 3, 7, 1, 9}
```

Say from these, I get the following results from my query (since it would have other WHERE clauses):

```
{6, 7, 23, 8, 1}
```

Finally, these results should be ordered using the set of IDs specified at the beginning so as to look something like this:

```
{8, 6, 23, 7, 1}
```

The reason I cannot do this in memory is because the query also has a .take() value (for example 10 rows), thus the ordering must be done in the query before the result set is limited, otherwise I might get loss of data.

In MySQL the equivalent of such a query would be:

```
ORDER BY CASE ID
WHEN 8 THEN 1
WHEN 6 THEN 2
WHEN 23 THEN 3
WHEN 3 THEN 4
WHEN 7 THEN 5
WHEN 1 THEN 6
WHEN 9 THEN 7
ELSE 8
```

It's important to note that I cannot make use of HQL or LINQ. Everything is done using Lambda expressions. I'm using NHibernate v3.3.0.4000, .NET 4.0 (C#), and MySQL Server v5.5.16.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to give a startingpoint, on QueryOver/Criteria you can add orders as a projection which can be a conditional

```
session.QueryOver<SomeClass>()
    .Where(lambdaExpression)
    .OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(...))
```